# Java driver dont fire query-start probe in postgres 11

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-11

While using SystemTap to trace postgres session on PostgreSQL 11.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36), 64-bit.

```
global livequeries

probe process("/usr/pgsql-11/bin/postgres").mark("query-start"){
  printf("[%s] Query start on PID %d : %s \n", ctime(gettimeofday_s()), pid(), user_string($arg1) )
  livequeries[tid(),$arg1] = gettimeofday_us()
}
```

psql fires this probe but java driver dont.

REF: [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dynamic-trace.html)

Comment: How is this the driver problem if SystemTap attaches to the _server_ process (I presume you're not running SystemTap on the client)?

Comment: When trying other drivers than JDBC the probe query-start is fired exactly as the documentation says but when using JDBC the probe query-start isn't fired and next fired probe is query-parse-start. Which prevents me from tracing applications sessions.

Comment: So why don't you just probe query-parse-start?

Comment: I need to probe `query-start` and `query-done` to get statistic (time of query) I need to debug the application. `query-parse-start` and `query-parse-done` would be time of query parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume the difference between you running your queries via `psql` vs. from a Java program is that you use prepared statements in Java. Processing "simple statements" and prepared statements take different code paths in the Postgres backend ([postgres.c](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/d1f04b96b99d595e80791cdb0faa9cfdde2a5afa/src/backend/tcop/postgres.c)).

"query-start" probe is only called when a simple statement is executed (`exec_simple_query`), while a prepared statement processing has two separate distinct stages: parse (`exec_parse_message`) and execute (`exec_execute_message`).

Both code paths converge when they call `PortalRun` in [pquery.c](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/97c39498e5ca9208d3de5a443a2282923619bf91/src/backend/tcop/pquery.c), where the "query-execute" probe is called.

In other words, the two code paths look like this (omitting the "done" probes):

```
psql -> simple statement
  query-start probe
  query-parse-start probe
  query-parse-done probe      
  query-rewrite-start probe
  query-rewrite-done probe
  query-plan-start probe
  query-plan-done probe
  query-execute-start probe
  query-execute-done probe
  query-done probe

JDBC -> prepared statement
  prepare phase
    query-parse-start probe
    query-parse-done probe     
  execute phase 
    query-execute-start probe
    query-execute-done probe
```

If you're not particularly concerned about the query parsing and planning latency, you need to capture the "query-execute-*" probes. If you need the query text, capture also "query-parse-start".